# How to submit multiple forms in one page using POST without refreshing page in Express JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, express

I am developing an application in ExpressJS, and plan to have the following HTML code in a jade file.

I have the following page with 4 form buttons:

```
<div class="dog">         
        <div class="dog_wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 left_sec">
        <div class="panel-heading">LIVE</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="livefeed-left">
        <form class="button" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="DEPLOY" id="fieldID" name="fieldName"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Raise"/>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="livefeed-right">
        <form class ="button" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="RECOVER" id="fieldID" name="fieldName"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Lower"/>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 right_sec">
   <div class="panel-heading" id="sample" style="width: 100%; height:500px">MAP</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="livefeed-left">
       <form class= "button" action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="UPLOAD" id="fieldID" name="fieldName"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="lngHolderID" name="lngHolderName"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="latHolderID" name="latHolderName"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="altHolderID" name="altHolderName"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="actHolderID" name="actHolderName"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="actParamHolderID" name="actParamHolderName"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="compileHolder()"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Each button will POST an action,however, it refreshes the page every time the user clicks on the button. I read on a separate post that this can be controlled through jQUERY or AJAX.

I added the following script at the end before the  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.button').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from causing a page refresh.
    var data = {
      username: $('#username').val(),
      password: $('#password').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/my/url',
      data: data,
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(function (response) {
      // Do stuff with the response, like add it to the page dynamically.
      $('body').append(response);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is for the following section:

```
 $('upload').on('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault(); // Stop the form from causing a page refresh.
var data = {
  username: $('#username').val(),
  password: $('#password').val()
};
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/my/url',
  data: data,
  method: 'POST'
}).then(function (response)
```

Would the above code work? Also, does `url: 'http://localhost/my/url'` take in the actual jade file. For example, `dogshow.jade`?

Sorry for the questions, I am pretty new at this and still feeling my way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this will not work.  If u want to send all form data as u name assigned in form just use single line.

```
var data = $('#upload').serialize();
```

Comment: Are you saying I can assign all the 4 forms to a single form id and use var data = $('#upload').serialize();?

Comment: But u have assigned upload Id to only one form.

Comment: Are you saying that I can assign upload ID to all forms, and change my var data to var data = $('#upload').serialize(); and it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `$('upload')` be `$('#upload')`? In jQuery id's are preceded by `#` sign.

Comment: I've updated my code to $(#upload), but can I use the same upload ID for all 4 forms?

Comment: HTML element id should be unique for DOM. If you need same attribute use class and within jQuery can be used with dot(.) preceding class name.

Comment: Yes, I just did that -- was reading about it a few minutes before.

Comment: For the  $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/my/url', would this be the page or the URL of the page? For example, dog.jade vs http://application.com/dog.jade